# Convert a 1d array to 2d with element placed diagonally

Tags: java

I tried this a lot but came with no solution.  i have to convert a 1d array of length 16 to a  4x4 2d array with elements placed diagonally in java

eg.
1d array as input:{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}

output required:

[image]

Comment: Post your code/ideas please.

Comment: Your output is a 1D array.

Comment: 4x4 2d array? I am sorry

Comment: Can you post what code you have tried already and where it is going wrong? This seems like homework.

Comment: **In case this is homework:** While Stackoverflow is meant to answer such questions, you should always provide some minimal code to show others what you've tried. This way we might be able to tell you where you've made some mistake (-> better learning experience for you). Don't get others to write all code for you, because you won't learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple:

1-Read the value in a One dimensional array

2- Make sure the length of array is 16

3- create a two dimensional array

4- Transverse the one dimensional array in a For Loop

5- Using the Nested for loops ,store the value from one dimension array to two dimension array

Comment: thx for the answer but i require the output to be similar to the one provided in the image. http://i.stack.imgur.com/CzP9Q.png

Comment: hi i did this thing only but it will result in an array that has numbers placed randomly . i want the element to be placed diagonally  just as given in the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/CzP9Q.png

Comment: How did you implement Nargis' answer? The fourth and fifth point don't suggest any specific algorithm, just the generic approach. If you're getting random output, you most likely wrote something that's not in that answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

ahh.. good question, for `n x n` problem:

```
int i = 0;
for (int diagonal_length = 1; diagonal_length <= n; ++diagonal_length) {
    for (int j = 0; j < diagonal_length; j++) {
        out[diagonal_length - j - 1][j] = in[i];
        ++i;
    }
}
```

I have left out the lower right triangle; should be easy to do that part given this.

Comment: the output is correct:-) thanks

Comment: this is asked in one of the interview and i am not able to solve it. good solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (pseudo-code; just to give you some random idea; I didn't test it; I assume it works, but there might be some bugs included):

```
input = array[n * m];
output = array[m][n];

var i = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

while (i < array.length) {
    if (x < n && y < m)
        output[y][x] = input[i++];
    if (y-- == 0) { // we're already at the "top"
        y = x + 1;  // move to the next row
        x = 0;      // reset the column
    }
}
```

Just to note that this is **not** the most efficient way to do this, but this should work.

**Important, in case this is some homework:**
While Stackoverflow is meant to answer such questions, you should always provide some minimal code to show others what you've tried. This way we might be able to tell you where you've made some mistake. Don't get others to write all code for you, because you won't learn from it. As such, I strongly urge you to try the code above, but only if you're able to understand what's actually going on. Once you do so, you can start implementing it on your own, only look if you're stuck.

Comment: have a look at this program.The problem completely solved.http://javawk.blogspot.in/2013/10/important-array-programto-traverse.html